# Job change; is this salary increase worth changing?

Tags: salary, job-change

I wanted to see if a 17.64% salary increase is worth changing jobs?

Keeping in mind the benefits are about the same. Thanks.

I really need to know if it’s worth making the job change.

Comment: There's no way _we_ can answer this question for you.

Comment: This question might be salvageable if you ask *how* to decide whether a salary increase is worth it rather than just asking us if we think the increase is enough.

Comment: Just financially speaking, not taking the change could put you years behind where you would otherwise be.  If you were to save the difference for example, it might allow you to retire a decade earlier (depending on your situation).

Comment: Ask yourself: **"Will I get a 17.64% raise in my current job any time soon?"**. If the answer is **Yes** then stay with your current employer, if the answer is **No** on the other hand, you can only gain by taking the offer and changing jobs.

Comment: It really depends how you measure "worth it". It's also worth mentioning how long you've been at your current company since it may effect future career prosepects if you're seen to "job-hop"

Answer (score 5):

This is something only you can really answer.

I suggest you **write down the pros and cons of your current job and this one** with higher salary. Then, consider each pro and con and decide what is best for *you*.

Consider also including things like company culture, commute time, things you will be learning, growth opportunity, etc., so you can have a better picture of both jobs in general.

If it were up to me, and if both jobs had the same benefits and pros, and the only difference would be that this has higher salary, then it would seem logical to decide for the higher salary one.